# Setup Magento on local server from live server

Tags: magento, installation

I need to setup magento on local server from live server.

I tries all the steps as I googled but its give me a 404 error. Can anyone point out me. Below are the log file report for your reference.

> failed to open stream: Permission denied  in
>   D:\xampp\htdocs\roller\lib\Varien\Simplexml\Config.php on line 496

I give permission all the file but still its give me this error in my error log. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: This line loads file content.  Could I suggest on line 495 you add a log of the file that it is requesting? Such as `Mage::log($filePath);` refresh the page, and then check your `var/log/system.log`  This should tell you which file it is failing to load.  My guess is your download has potentially missed a file, or your permissions for that folder/file aren't correct.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Give the permission to app and etc folders